# Update TextView in a custom View

Tags: android, textview, android-custom-view

I have a half screen custom view and a TextView in my activity.

```
<com.sted.test.mainView
    android:id="@+id/mainView" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

<TextView android:id="@+id/tvScore" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

Upon clicking on the custom view, how can I update the TextView in my activity?

Currently I have this piece of coding in my custom view's `onTouchEvent()` but it hits a NullPointerException in the `setText()` part. Should I never update the TextView in my custom view?

```
TextView tvScore = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvScore);
tvScore.setText("Updated!");
```

Comment: check where you setContentView you have given the proper layout or not and also while giving setText before that itself you have to declare that textview if you did all these things then on error in this part of code error is outside this code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't "see" the TextView tvScore in your custom view's code. `findViewById()` looks for views in the hierarchy starting from the view from which you're calling it, or from hierarchy root if you're calling `Activity.findViewById()` (and of course this works only after `setContentView()`).

If your custom view was a compound view like say a linear layour containing some TextViews, then it would make sense using `findViewById()` in there.

The solution is finding the textview for example in `onCreate()` and then passing it to the custom view in some way (like some `set..()` method).

**EDIT**

If in your custom view you have something like:

```
public class CustomView extends View {
    ...
    TextView tvToUpdate;
    public void setTvToUpdate(TextView tv) {
        tvToUpdate = tv;
    }
    ...
}
```

you can do something like:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    CustomView cv = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customview);
    TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);
    cv.setTvToUpdate(tv);
    ...
}
```

so that since then you would have a reference to the textview inside your custom view's code. It would be like some sort of setup.